# How to get the last windows active time by windows api

Tags: winapi

In general, the Screensaver will run when we do nothing for a period of time.
Now i wanna know how to get the unactive time.
In another word,i want to make a program which would run a function if we do nothing for a period of time.
Now i can use mouse or keyboard hook to solve the problem.
But you know,it needs administrator permissions. In another word,if in win vista or win 7,it is nauseating because of the UAC.
I need an API such to get last windows active time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CallNtPowerInformation()` API is to get the last power information
I should use [`GetLastInputInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: GetLastInputInfo() does not give you system-wide idle time for when Windows will go idle or when the screensaver will kick in.  It only gives you the idle time for the running process.  CallNtPowerInformation() gives you the system idle time.

Comment: @JohnDeters The documentation states something different: "GetLastInputInfo provides session-specific user input information for only the session that invoked the function." I would interpret session as "user session" aka RDS session.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [CallNtPowerInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372675%28VS.85%29.aspx) and request a SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION structure.

Comment: The SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION structure "Contains information about the idleness of the system."  TimeRemaining is "The time remaining in the idle timer, in seconds."  Idleness is that number expressed as a percentage.

typedef struct _SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION {
  ULONG MaxIdlenessAllowed;
  ULONG Idleness;
  ULONG TimeRemaining;
  UCHAR CoolingMode;
}SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION;