# User idle time C windows and linux

Tags: c, windows, idle-timer

How could I get user idle time on Windows in seconds?

I wrote small program to check work time on pure `C`, but all answers that I could find were written in `C#`.
Is there a way to get it like on `MacOSX` or `X11`?

For `OSX` I used this solution - https://github.com/kairichard/idler

And for Linux - https://github.com/gpolitis/xidle

Comment: [`CallNtPowerInformation()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442246/how-to-get-the-last-windows-active-time-by-windows-api) with `SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION` seems to do, what you want.

Comment: It seems like what i need! Have you any code snippet shows how to use it? Unfortunately i never build program for windows system. If i understand correctly i need wrap function for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx , but this example on c++ not on pure c.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pAgcc2Z4 am i right?

Comment: Idleness  is the "percentage of idleness" the system considers itself to be in (whatever that is). `SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.TimeRemaining` is essentially *time till the screensaver is activated*, which is also not all that useful. However, If I get the linked answer right, `GetTickCount() - GetLastUserInput()` should give you time since last user input in msecs, which is pretty close to what xidle does, too.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for Windows?